# How do I use a forms action attribute to work with an object pk in django?

Tags: html, django, forms

I have a form which needs to use the pk of the object its use is needed for. How do I write the url in the action attribute instead of leaving it blank?

The url conf is this:
   `path('add/<int:pk>/', ObjectView.as_view(), name='add')`

The link to the form from the other template pages is this:

`<a href="{% url 'app:add_users' object.id %}">Form</a>`

The class handling it is pretty basic with get and post which currently accept `**kwargs` for the object's `pk`

So how do I edit the action attr to work when not left blank in the form?:

```
  <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            
            {{ form }}
    
            <input type="submit" value="Invite">
            
    </form>
```

Comment: an object pk for what? You view seems to add/create something, so what would the id be used for?

Comment: Adding a field to the specific object which is referenced in the prior view. So `somevar = Object.objects.get(id=pk)`  then do stuff with `somevar`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I had to pass the object as the context to the forms get request and and access the attributes I needed there.

```
 def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        form = ObjectTeamAddForm()
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        object = Object.objects.get(pk=pk)

        return render(request, 'locations/invite.html', {"form": form,"object": object})
```

The action tag then looks like:
`<form id="invite" action="{% url 'locations:invite' object.id %}" method="POST">`

And I can do stuff in the post view with the id/pk.